# Proxy access.log file or dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm a undergraduate student and I am doing a study relating to replacement algorithms that requires the *access.log* of proxy systems. I have searched for access.log datasets for this purpose on the following links:

- [Data.Gov](http://www.data.gov/)
- [Socrata](https://www.socrata.com/resources)
- [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/)
- [UCLA Dept of Statistics](http://statistics.ucla.edu/)
- [“Let Me Get That Data For You”](https://github.com/opendata/lmgtdfy/)

But I couldn't find anything that meets my needs. Are there any sites that provide proxy access.log datasets? Help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What type of proxy are you looking for?  Typical web proxies that are open to the public? If so, I honestly doubt you'll find it unless you stumble upon it on accident.

Comment: Squid proxy log files, particularly `access.log`